# Repeat same component with different data in dropdown- angular 5

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular-components

Here is Structure of my drop-down list

Companies > Depots

each company has multiple depots
I have created a component for company and after onclick service http request on company(menu item) I bring all companies and loop companies into the company component.
I am doing same with depots(menu item inside company), bring list of depots and show it inside depot component

Now here is my problem,
When I get list of depots onclick of depots(menu item) but as I loop through the deports all deports of all companies shows the same list of depots, so it actually bind depot list of all depot component available on the page,

I just want to show list of depots of that particular company.

Any Help is really appreciated

**This is my code :**

The Hierarchy is => Company->Depot

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="onClickCompanies()">company</a>
<!-- code of company component start here -->
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let company of companies" class="childul levels">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" >{{company.CompanyName}}</a>   
    <ul class="nested-menu-items parentsul">
        <li class="childul levels">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="onClickDepot(company.CompanyID)">Depots</a>
<!-- code of depot component start here -->
            <ul class="nested-menu-items parentsul">
                <li class="childul levels" *ngFor="let companyDepot of companyDepots">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">{{companyDepot.DepotName}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
<!-- code of depot component end here -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</li></ul><!-- code of company component end here -->
```

**Here is application view :**

[This is actual image after clicking depot of New Company 2 And also getting append to new comapny 1 and next all too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YaLk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each company you should have an list of depots! companies should be something like this:

```
interface company{
  CompanyID:number;
  CompanyName:string;
  depots:depots[];
  }

 interface depots{
  DepotName:string;
  }
 companies=company[];

onClickDepot(id)
{
  let depotsById = getDepots(id);//this function gets the depots
   let company = this.companies.find((x)=>x.CompanyID==id)
  company.depots=depotsById;
}

    in html:
    <!-- code of company component start here -->
    <ul>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="onClickCompanies()">company</a>


    <li *ngFor="let company of companies" class="childul levels">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" >{{company.CompanyName}}</a>   
        <ul class="nested-menu-items parentsul">
            <li class="childul levels">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="onClickDepot(company.CompanyID)">Depots</a>
    <!-- code of depot component start here -->
                <ul class="nested-menu-items parentsul">
                    <li class="childul levels" *ngFor="let companyDepot of company.depots ">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">{{companyDepot.DepotName}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
    <!-- code of depot component end here -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li></ul><!-- code of company component end here -->
```

Comment: WOW , It's works for me.
Thanks Man , You save my lots of time.
It's Actually works as we want.
thanks again...!!!